# data.table is not filtering correctly

Tags: r, filter, data.table

While using data.table and filtering I am getting wrong results.

I am exposing here a reproducible example to see the problem:

```
set.seed(123)
results <- data.table(id = 1:1000000, v1 = rnorm(1000000))
rs <- data.table(type = 1:1000000 %% 5, prob = rnorm(1000000))

results[, `:=`(cls = rs$type, cls.prob = rs$prob)]
results[cls != 0 & abs(v1 - cls.prob) < 0.3, `:=`(cls = 3, cls.prob = 1)]
summary(results[cls == 4, cls])
   # Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   #    4       4       4       4       4       4 
results[cls != 0 & abs(v1 - cls.prob) < 0.2, `:=`(cls = 3, cls.prob = 1)]
summary(results[cls == 4, cls])
   # Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   #    4       4       4       4       4       4 
results[cls != 0 & abs(v1 - cls.prob) < 0.5, `:=`(cls = 3, cls.prob = 1)]
summary(results[cls == 4, cls])
   # Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   # 3.00    4.00    4.00    3.87    4.00    4.00
```

As you can see the last summary should ouput 4 in every slot.

Does anyone know what is going on?

I am working on this version of R

```
>version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-suse-linux-gnu       
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.3                         
year           2015                        
month          03                          
day            09                          
svn rev        67962                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
nickname       Smooth Sidewalk
```

and this version of data.table:

```
> packageVersion('data.table')
[1] ‘1.9.4’
```

Comment: Version `1.10.4.3` of data.table no strange behaviour with your code on Windows

Comment: Same for me, code works perfectly. I guess you executed a line manually before your summary

Comment: I have checked with a newer version and it also works for me, I suspect it has to do with the version of data.table but we can not upgrade it at the moment...

Comment: I suggest opening an issue on their github site. Likely they will provide an answer if some bug was fixed between version you are using and 1.10.4.3 (Clemsangs version). Their issue page can be found [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).